# Best way to load pictures for custom cognito emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I would like to have some images in my automated emails sent by AWS Cognito. What is the best practice, where should I store them, how should I load them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognito automated emails support html content. In this case you have 2 options.

- Use external links as src like: 
  Img src="https://s3bucket_folder.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/your_company_log.png"
- Use base 64 equivalent of the image in the src

The external link solution is the most common, as base64 code is hard to maintain and not all mainstream mail client (Gmail ) supports it.